# What is the height of a triangle if base and diagonal of bigger triangle are known?

Tags: probability

I am currently studying Statistical Inference class on Coursera. In one of the assignments, the following question comes up.

> [image]
>
> Consider this figure - a rectangle with height 1 and width 2 with a diagonal line drawn
>    from the lower left corner (0,0) to the upper right (2,1). The area of the entire
>    rectangle is 2 and elementary geometry tells us that the diagonal divides the rectangle
>    into 2 equal areas.
>
> Now consider the shaded portion of the triangle - a smaller triangle with a base of length
>    $1.6$ and height determined by the diagonal. We'll answer the question, "What proportion of
>    the big triangle is shaded?"
>
> We have to compute the area of the blue triangle. (Since the area of the big triangle is
>    $1$, the area of the blue triangle is the proportion of the big triangle that is shaded.) We
>    know the base, but what is its height?
>
> The slope of a line is the "rise" (change in height) divided by the "run" (change in width), so the diagonal's slope is $\frac12$. **At $x=1.6$, the $y$ value of the diagonal is $\frac12 \times 1.6$.**

Why to find the height is the diagonal multiplied by the base?

Comment: The diagonal's equation is $y=0.5 \cdot x$, from where you can find the height by plugging in $x=1.6$, pretty intuitive.

Comment: thanks i guess i forget to think about it.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that you can use proportionality.

The triangles are similar, the ratio of two corresponding sides is $\frac{1.6}{2}$ or $0.8.$

Thus the ratio of areas is $0.8^2,$ and it is also the area of the shaded triangle.

Answer (score 0):

If you think about it the following way it hopefully makes more sense.

The equation for the line of the diagonal is y= 1/2x + 0 .

Therefore to find the height (the y values) we replace x with the point on the x axis.

In this case x = 1.6. So really we just have y = 1/2 (1.6) + 0.

So while it might look strange to just multiply the slope with the x value to get the height if we think about basic algebra we can see where the formula comes from.